# React native Facebook login issue on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook, mobile

I have already Facebook login integrated with my react native project, all was good and working fine until 2 days ago I faced an issue with Facebook login on IOS. If the user choose to continue the login using the web-view or browser, the login get a success response, but if he choose to continue the login using the Facebook app, here the issue appear on some IOS devices and others no (Note: Most of devices that has been used to test this issue have the same IOS version). [Press to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzTH3.png) here the issue happen here in this screenshot, the user press on "Login with the Facebook app", then press "Continue as 'user profile on Facebook'" till here all is good, after this a loader appear and then take the user to the screen in the screenshot. No error or warning is returned from the Facebook login neither a success.

I have tried many solutions like remove the package used react-native-fbsdk-next and use react-native-fbsdk, also I tried to redo the integration of react-native-fbsdk-next, and I tried to downgrade the version of the package, and the issue still there